# Matplotlib storing plots as vars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I've been wanting to store two plots as vars. I've tried(when creating them):

```
x = np.arange(0.2,10,0.01)
y = x+2
plt.figure(1) //maybe this could work
plt.plot(x,y)
```

This would plot correct and then another one

```
   plt.figure(2) //changing the var maybe
    y = x**2
    plt.plot(x,y) //plotting different one
```

But then I write plt.figure(1) again but the first plot doesn't show up.
What I don't want is to change the y var again to be able to plot the 1st plot (as the x var is the same on both, only the y one changes)

How can I implement a solution to this?
Thanks